# SSRS start / stop

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I want to create a SQL Job to stop and re-start the Report Server out of working hours but I am having trouble creating the SQL code that will allow this to happen.

I was thinking along the lines of using something like:-

> NET STOP ReportServer
>
> NET START ReportServer

but don't know the best way to incorporate this into a command code?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write any SQL code to do that. SQL Agent Jobs can also have job steps of type "CmdExec" which execute operating system commands.

Just create two jobs, one for stopping one for starting the reporting services service.
Add a jobstep of type "CmdExec" to each, providing the commands you already listed in your question (`net stop ...` and `net start ...`).

You create the jobs via the SSMS UI, or via SQL commands. You can create the later with the "Script" button from the UI.

For illustration purposes, here is an *excerpt* showing the creation of the job step to stop the service:

```
...

USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'StopSSRS', @step_name=N'StopSSRS', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'CmdExec', 
        @command=N'net.exe stop ReportService', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
GO
...
```

Comment: That's great.  Much easier way of doing that. Thanks.